# GraphQL to PostgresQL type mapping

Tags: postgresql, types, mapping, graphql

First of all I have to admit: I'm quiet new to GraphQL. But nevertheless I am trying to generate "GraphQLObjectType" schemata out of the database metadata.

I am looking for a **mapping** between the **GraphQLTypes** and PostgresQL basic column types.

The following list contains the most interesting types in postgresQL:

bool, text, date, time, timestamp, numeric, integer, interval, bytea, json, timestamptz, bigint, jsonb

So far I could find the following mapping while digging in several projects like postgraphql.

postgresType -> GraphQLType

text -> GraphQLString

integer -> GraphQLInt

boolean -> GraphQLBoolean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for `numeric` type, if your problem domain is fine with `real` or `double precision`, you can use `GraphQLFloat` type. They all implement the same IEEE 754 spec. For more details, see [GraphQL spec](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-Float) and PostgreSQL documentation on [floating-point types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html).

GraphQL currently does not support as many default data types as PostgreSQL. However, it is possible to develop custom GraphQL types using the generic types available in GraphQL. Check out an awesome guide [Deep Dive into GraphQL Type System](https://github.com/mugli/learning-graphql/blob/master/7.%20Deep%20Dive%20into%20GraphQL%20Type%20System.md) to see how to do that. Another example is [graphql-custom-types](https://github.com/stylesuxx/graphql-custom-types).